# Problem with TdxComponentPrinter (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, printing, devexpress

[`TdxComponentPrinter`](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExPrintingSystem/Features.xml) is a componenet that allow me print a `TPanel` on a paper. But there is problem and when the panel contains TImage, the background of the image will be converted to black in the paper.

Before print :

[image]

After print (on the paper) :

[image]

I have tried different ways to solve this problem. for example i used `Repaint;` method of TPanel,...
but doesn't work and the background of image is still black. I don't know why!!!

Help me please.

Comment: Do you mean TdxComponentPrinter from DevExpress?

Comment: Sorry, missed your `devexpress` tag.

Comment: Ask devexpress. They will help you.

Comment: @David: +1. I suggest going to the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/MyIssues.aspx). You'll probably get a good answer quick.

Answer (score 5):

This is a png file, which might not be supported completely in your Delphi version. Did you try to change it to a TcxImage which might be more compatible with the DevExpress printing system?

It also might be worth it to [submit this issue to DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) if you can't fix it. They reply really quick and know more about their components then all of use here on SO :-)

Comment: Yes, they've got the best support center in the world :-)

Comment: Thank you, but I have converted the image to JPG format before.

Answer (score 0):

If it is already a jpg then you should improve the quality of the jpg. It looks like the black parts are compression artifacts where there is a mix between white and another color. If you clean up the background of the image with a paint program it will probably look a lot better.