# How to draw a picture on a TPanel

Tags: delphi, panel, draw, image

How can i draw a picture on a `TPanel`? I also want to determine X,Y to define exact position on the Panel.

Comment: Yes I have. but still doesn't work and now i want to draw the picture using Windows API.

Comment: Would you help me to draw the picture using Windows API? (canvas)

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question and *specificly* ask for a TCanvas solution. Or don't you even want that and want to do it winapi style? This one is answered.

Comment: @Lars - it relates to the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090783/problem-with-tdxcomponentprinter-delphi) when the JPG file (without transparency) on a panel is printed [this way](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ewOER.jpg). These comments are the garbage from our previous conversation, but still I have no clue why this happens.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple code

```
var
  eu:TImage;
begin
  eu:=TImage.Create(Panel1);
  eu.Parent:=Panel1;
  eu.Top:=30; // You can adjust the position by using these coordinates
  eu.Left:=50;
  eu.Picture.LoadFromFile('D:\usb.ico'); // Load any supported image
  eu.Visible:=True;
end;
```